# Почему в коде не срабатывают циклы?

Tags: javascript, циклы

Почему не срабатывают циклы в коде? Вместо массива из трех значений [min, max, avrage] выдает билиберду, тесты показывают, что циклы вообще не выполняются.

```
function statistics(arr) {
  var lenght = arr.lenght;
  var a = [];
  var min = arr[0];
  var max = min;
  console.log("test1");
  for(var i = 1; i < arr.lenght; i++) {
      if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
      if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i];
    console.log("test2");
  }
  a[0] = min;
  a[1] = max;
  var temp = 0;
  for (var j=0; j<arr.lenght; j++){
     temp += arr[j];
    console.log("test3");
  }
  a[2] = temp/arr.lenght;
  return a;
}
var v = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
console.log(statistics(v));
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладкой для выяснения сего факта

Comment: потому что длина это `length` а не `lenght`